# Placing of external virtual tables

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, compilation, vtable

From [Large-Scale C++ Software Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620) (Lakos), page 652:

> The question is, "In which unique translation unit will the compiler deposit the virtual table definition(s) for a given class?". The trick employed by CFRONT (and many other C++ implementations) is to place the external virtual tables in the translation unit that defines the lexically first non-inline function that appears in the class (if one exists).

Is this still the case with the most used compilers (GCC and Visual C++)? Or was it ever?

Comment: This is purely implementation defined.A compiler may not even have virtual table or virtual pointer and implement dynamic dispatch in its own preferred way.

Comment: i was under the impression that it is now more common to export the vtable in the TU which contains the definition of the first external *virtual* definition. if no such definition qualifies, then you may end up with a lot of copies of private extern vtables. echo: implementation defined

Comment: I was actually under the impression that the clang++ linker prints a "NOTE" line when it complains about a missing vtable, but I couldn't get it do that with a test program. Maybe they removed it, but it did mention something like the first non-inline virtual member, which would provide a hint where that particular compiler places the vtable. Yeah, I've seen it more than a few times...

Comment: The comments were likely accurate in 1996 (when the book was published, or 1995 when it was probably written).  That is a long time ago now, though, and things have undoubtedly changed since then.  As noted though, the issue is purely implementation defined.

Comment: @Als: Oh yes, there are infinitely many things the compiler *may* do. The question however is practical, it's what the listed compilers actually do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "_As noted though, the issue is purely implementation defined._" Technically it isn't even implementation defined: "implementation defined" means that implementations are required to describe their behavior in their documentation. Lookup "implementation defined quantities" in GCC manual.

Comment: @Als "_A compiler may not even have virtual table or virtual pointer and implement dynamic dispatch in its own preferred way._" Still, in practice, every real world compiler uses vtables, vptr...

Comment: +1 It's a valid question. Not the most critical or fascinating C++, but a valid question about real world implementations.

Comment: Modern linkers often have the ability to merge several copies of the same symbol definition, therefore it is no longer as important if there are several copies of the virtual table generated for the same class; they'll most likely get merged when linking. However, if the destructor is virtual (and thus an out of line version must be generated), it would make most sense to put the virtual table where the destructor is. Of course, of the out-of-line version of the destructor there *also* might be copies in several translation units if the destructor is declared inline.

Comment: @curiousguy: yes, you're correct. There's also an issue of ABI (application binary interfaces). If there is a C++ ABI for a given platform, then the compilers on that platform will be expected to follow it.  ABIs exist for C for sure; I'm not sure about C++.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, there is the ["C++ ABI for Itanium"](http://mentorembedded.github.com/cxx-abi/). (It's a generic ABI, for any architecture with a C ABI, not just for Itanium.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC happens to document that it behaves as described in the question (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html):

> VTables
>
> C++ virtual functions are implemented in most compilers using a lookup table, known as a vtable. The vtable contains pointers to the virtual functions provided by a class, and each object of the class contains a pointer to its vtable (or vtables, in some multiple-inheritance situations). If the class declares any non-inline, non-pure virtual functions, the first one is chosen as the “key method” for the class, and the vtable is only emitted in the translation unit where the key method is defined.
>
> Note: If the chosen key method is later defined as inline, the vtable will still be emitted in every translation unit which defines it. Make sure that any inline virtuals are declared inline in the class body, even if they are not defined there.

However, even in situations where there might be several vtables across several object files (as can happen if the 'key method' turns out to be inline), the compiler arranges for the duplicates to be ignored if possible, but the duplicates may end up using space in the final binary if the target doesn't support COMDAT:

> When used with GNU ld version 2.8 or later on an ELF system such as
>   GNU/Linux or Solaris 2, or on Microsoft Windows, duplicate copies of
>   these constructs will be discarded at link time. This is known as
>   COMDAT support.
>
> On targets that don't support COMDAT, but do support weak symbols, GCC
>   will use them. This way one copy will override all the others, but the
>   unused copies will still take up space in the executable.
>
> For targets which do not support either COMDAT or weak symbols, most
>   entities with vague linkage will be emitted as local symbols to avoid
>   duplicate definition errors from the linker. This will not happen for
>   local statics in inlines, however, as having multiple copies will
>   almost certainly break things.

FWIW, GCC seems to use a symbol that starts with `__ZTV` for the vtable.

As far as MSVC is concerned, some empirical testing with VC++10 (I don't think MS documents the behavior) shows that it seems that VC doesn't attempt to limit the vtable to a single object file. Since Microsoft knows that it can rely on the linker supporting COMDAT sections and since constructors are the only functions that use a vtable directly (all other vtable uses are indirect through the object pointer, I believe), it looks like VC just places a copy of the vtable in any object file where a constructor is instantiated.  For classes that use the compiler generated ctor, that would be anywhere an object of that type is constructed.

Comment: "_constructors are the only functions_" with some (not all) destructors?